# extract multiple numbers from a string and replace the whole string with a new string containing the numbers in r

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I have a string like below:

```
s = 'regimen A1 Cycle 3 Day 5 treatment B1 '
```

what I need to do is replace the whole string as `C3D5` (cycle 3 day 5). I wonder how to do that using regular expression? 
I tried:

```
str_replace(s, '.*Cycle\\s+(\\d+)Day\\s+(\\d+).*', 'C\\1D\\2' )
```

what I got is the original string. Could anyone tell me what I did wrong? Any elegant way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex is off - you missed a space between the first digit and `Day`, in which case the pattern doesn't match, so no replacement happens. Try:

```
str_replace(s, '.*Cycle\\s+(\\d+)\\s+Day\\s+(\\d+).*', 'C\\1D\\2' )
#                                ^^^^
# [1] "C3D5"
```